# How to get current data connectivity type (3G, Edge, Gprs) in Microsoft .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I'm developing mobile apps using the Microsoft .NET 3.5 Compact Framework.

I need to periodically check for what kind of data connectivity is up (3G, Edge, or Gprs).

Can I get this information via the .NET CF API?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without periodically checking,  the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status namespace allows you to subscribe to particular properties associated with the data connection of the device.  By setting up a SystemState subscription you can assign events when the connection changes:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status;

    public void OnLoad()
    {
        var connectionState = new SystemState(SystemProperty.ConnectionsCellularCount);
        connectionState.Changed += (o, s) =>
            {
                if (SystemState.CellularSystemConnectedHsdpa)
                {
                    // show 3G Icon
                }
                else if (SystemState.CellularSystemConnectedGprs)
                {
                    // show GPRS Icon
                }
                else if (SystemState.CellularSystemConnectedEdge)
                {
                    // show Edge Icon
                }
            };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the current information (without the `.Changed` event)? I tried testing the value of each `SystemState.CellularSystemConnectedXXXX` just after instantiating `SystemState`, and all of them returned false